# ngModel.$parsers ingore whitespace at the end of ng-model value

Tags: javascript, angularjs, validation, angularjs-directive

I have directive like this:

```
  .directive('noWhitespace', ['$parse', function($parse) {
    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      require: 'ngModel',
      link: function (scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
        /*
        scope.$watch(attrs.ngModel, function(value) {
          var getter = $parse(value);
          update(getter(scope));
        });
        */
        function update(viewValue) {
          console.log(JSON.stringify(viewValue));
          if (viewValue.match(/\s/)) {
            ngModel.$setValidity('whitespace', false);
            return undefined;
          } else {
            ngModel.$setValidity('whitespace', true);
            return viewValue;
          }
        }
        ngModel.$parsers.unshift(update);
      }
    };
  }])
```

and when I use it like this:

```
<form name="something" novalidate>
  <input ng-model="myValue" no-whitespace/>
  <div ng-show="something.myValue.$error.whitespace">
    Error
  </div>
</form>
```

and I type something and then few spaces at the end `update` is not called until I type character after those spaces and then I got error that I have whitespace. (the same happen when I put spaces at the begining or only spaces). Why is that, and how to fix it? As you see in comments I've try to use `$watch+$parse` but got error `Cannot read property 'match' of undefined`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this in your template:

```
<form name="something" novalidate>
  <input ng-model="myValue" no-whitespace ng-trim="false"/>
  <div ng-show="something.myValue.$error.whitespace">
    Error
  </div>
</form>
```

That should solve the issue of ng-model not updating when you enter empty space.

EDIT: Derp, the attribute goes in the input element not in the div ...

Comment: why ng-trim on div and not on input?

Comment: Edited... sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

This is the expected behavior of model parsers in angular, the idea being that if the entered text is incorrect (has whitespace in the end), the `ngModel` should return `undefined`. When you think about it, why would you save a value to `ngModel` anyway if it's not correct according to your validations?

This is the relevant bit:

```
if (viewValue.match(/\s/)) {
  ngModel.$setValidity('whitespace', false);
  return undefined;
}
```

You are setting validity to false and returning `undefined`.

You can keep the model updated even if its value isn't validated by just returning `viewValue` always:

```
if (viewValue.match(/\s/)) 
  ngModel.$setValidity('whitespace', false);
else 
  ngModel.$setValidity('whitespace', true);

// Return viewvalue regardless of whether it validates or not
return viewValue;
```

Comment: In my code `console.log(JSON.stringify(viewValue));` is not executed when I type space at the end or in the begining. I can remove my code and $parser will still not fire.

Comment: In that case I misunderstood the question, but @Wavy's answer looks like it should do the trick, although I agree `ngTrim` should be on the input. See the docs https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Btext%5D